# How can I decompose the error after an ARIMA estimation, and how do I store the estimated values?

Tags: estimation, arima, stata, error

EDIT (in response to Stephan's comments): I was able to read a paper by Bessembinder & Seguin (1992) on futures trading and stock price volatility, wherein they used the ARIMA model to decompose the error into two separate components (the seasonality component, as well as the random component). Is this possible to do on Stata? Specifically, how do I get the estimated values of the different components of the error, and then store them? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You will probably get better answers if you edit your question to explain just *how* you want to decompose errors using ARIMA. Few people here will start looking for a paper (please give the full citation and a link), then read the paper to figure out what B&S did, then make the effort to understand "the same thing I am trying to do" (which should perhaps be a separate question), finally write up an answer. Please make it a bit easier for us to help you. Thank you!